# Complicated sentence in “To Kill a Mockingbird”: Meaning of "lest", and is "might" omitted?

Tags: word-meaning, conjunctions, ellipsis

I have another question about the complicated sentence in *[To Kill a Mockingbird](http://www.penfield.edu/webpages/jgarbarino/files/to_kill_a_mockingbird_text.pdf)*. The complicated sentence is in the paragraph below.

> *Being Southerners, it was a source of shame to some members of the family that we had no recorded ancestors on either side of the Battle of Hastings. All we had was Simon Finch, a fur-trapping apothecary from Cornwall whose piety was exceeded only by his stinginess. In England, Simon was irritated by the persecution of those who called themselves Methodists at the hands of their more liberal brethren, and as Simon called himself a Methodist, he worked his way across the Atlantic to Philadelphia, thence to Jamaica, thence to Mobile, and up the Saint Stephens. **Mindful of John Wesley’s strictures on the use of many words in buying and selling, Simon made a pile practicing medicine, but in this pursuit he was unhappy lest he be tempted into doing what he knew was not for the glory of God, as the putting on of gold and costly apparel.** So Simon, having forgotten his teacher’s dictum on the possession of human chattels, bought three slaves and with their aid established a homestead on the banks of the Alabama River some forty miles above Saint Stephens. He returned to Saint Stephens only once, to find a wife, and with her established a line that ran high to daughters. Simon lived to an impressive age and died rich.*

(The complicated sentence is *"Mindful of John Wesley’s strictures on the use of many words in buying and selling, Simon made a pile practicing medicine, but in this pursuit he was unhappy lest he be tempted into doing what he knew was not for the glory of God, as the putting on of gold and costly apparel"*.)

Does the word ***[lest](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lest)*** mean "in order to make sure that something will not happen" in the sentence *"but in this pursuit he was unhappy lest he be tempted into doing what he knew was not for the glory of God, as the putting on of gold and costly apparel"*?

Is the word ***might*** omitted in the sentence *"lest he be tempted into doing what he knew was not for the glory of God"*?

Comment: The *be* employed as a finite verb marks the clause as 'subjunctive', so you are right to think that it has the *sense* of *might b* or *should be*.

Comment: *Lest* is rarely used nowadays, so it's not surprising that most of us are not familiar with it. My advice is: try to read it as "for fear that".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> *Mindful of John Wesley’s strictures on the use of many words in buying and selling, Simon made a pile practicing medicine, but in this pursuit he was unhappy lest he be tempted into doing what he knew was not for the glory of God, as the putting on of gold and costly apparel.*

will be much easier to understand if we replace these following parts:

- *Mindful of* ~ "Being mindful of" (i.e., "Being careful about", "Heeding")
- *strictures* ~ "criticisms"
- *(the use of) many words* ~ "(perhaps unethical) advertisement; marketing hype"
- *made a pile* ~ "made a lot of money"
- *lest* ~ "for fear that" (i.e., be afraid that something might happen)
- *be tempted* ~ "might be tempted"
- *as* ~ "such as"
- *the putting on of* ~ "wearing"

which allows us to read the original sentence like this:

> Being mindful of John Wesley's criticisms on the marketing hype in buying and selling, Simon made a lot of money practicing medicine, but in this pursuit he was unhappy for fear that he might be tempted into doing what he knew was not for the glory of God, such as wearing gold and costly apparel.

---

To answer your direct questions:

Q: Does the word *lest* mean "in order to make sure that something will not happen"?

> Not quite so. The second definition given by Longman is closer, i.e., "used to show that someone is afraid or worried that a particular thing might happen". (Or in short "for fear that", as I choose to use in the interpretation above.)

Q: Is the word *might* omitted in the sentence "lest he be tempted into doing what he knew was not for the glory of God"?

> Not really. *Lest* is often used with verb in its subjunctive form (i.e., its plain form). Here is an example from another dictionary: *he spent whole days in his room, wearing headphones lest he disturb anyone*. Note the form *disturb* (rather than *disturbs*). Having said that, reading this *be* as if it were *might be* is possible and quite practical for learners.

<sub>(Hope this helps. And welcome to ELL!)</sub>

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Dear Sir, the word " might " is not omitted in the sentence " lest he be tempted into doing what he knew was not for the glory of God ". Thank you so much for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

**Lest** has the meaning **let it not happen**. A phrase which gets used from time to time is

> **Lest we forget**
>   **Lest we forget** where we came from

meaning **let it not happen** that we forget our roots

Adding **might** may sound more familiar to most people

> Lest he **might** be tempted

Which has the meaning of **possibly** being tempted. However, one must keep in mind that these are **Methodists** that are being talked about, and with that understanding, **being tempted** is not a question of **if** but of **when**. Simon is **successful but unhappy**, which may make him especially susceptible to materialistic temptation, and with temptation there is a price to be paid (think: [fire and brimstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_and_brimstone)).

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Dear Sir, what does the word "it " in the sentence " being tempted is not a question of if but of when " refer to? Thank you so much for your help again.

Comment: "It is not a question of **if** but of **when**". If "it is a question of **if**" it means something might happen or it might not happen: **if** it happens. If "it is a question of **when**" only means the time something will happen. The sentence means that something **will** definitely happen (not a question of **if** ) the only thing to worry about is **when** does it happen

Comment: The **it** is whatever you are **thinking about / writing about** that is going to happen

Comment: I am really sorry. My question should be "  what does the word " if " in the sentence " being tempted is not a question of if but of when " refer to?

Comment: Dear Sir, did you study the novel " To Kill a Mockingbird " in high school?

Comment: It's one of the **required readings** in high school. I hope you are enjoying it

Comment: Dear Sir, except for the novel " To Kill a Mockingbird ", what other English novels did you read in high school?

Comment: Catcher on the Rye, Lord of the Flies, Great Gatsby, Animal Farm, The Iliad, The Odyssey, A Tale of Two Cities, Great Expectations, Brave New World, 1984, Heart of Darkness, Catch-22, My Antonia, Scarlett Letter to name a few.  Are you reading mainly to learn better English or also to understand culture?

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. I read the novel " To Kill a Mockingbird " mainly to improve my English level.